# How to Add XSD and XSI as an Attribute

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd

I am pretty new to this and am now stumped.  I need to add the xsd and xsi under an element but am unsure how to do this.  I looked around on this sight but could not not find what I was looking for (maybe I'm not searching correctly).

I am building an XSLT XML and need to have both the xsd and xsi included to look like this:

```
<BxfMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF”>
```

I have the element name set as BxfMessage, but what is the correct way to add these schemas (presumably as an attribute?)

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me you are slightly confused about XSLT, XSD, xsi and so on - this makes it very unclear what you are asking. I suggest you take some time understanding the concepts before asking the next question on SO.

But since I am writing anyway, your question might be how to assign a namespace to an element in your XML file?

Let's examine a simple example XML:

```
<root>
  <node/>
  <node/>
</root>
```

The XML file above does not have any namespaces. If there are namespaces, you usually declare them on the *root* element (also called document node), like this:

```
<bxf:root xmlns:bxf="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF”>
  <bxf:node/>
  <bxf:node/>
</bxf:root>
```

Now, to answer (what I guess is) your question: You assign a namespace to an element by *prefixing* the latter, in this case with `bxf`. Since all elements belong to this namespace, you could also declare a default namespace:

```
<root xmlns="http://smpte-ra.org/schemas/2021/2008/BXF”>
  <node/>
  <node/>
</root>
```

which means that unprefixed elements have a namespace, too.